# How to update image of ImageView in Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I am trying to click on imageview of custom listview and want to change their image on onClick event.  I am able to click on it success to do my other operation but images not reflected of imageview.

Here is code for reference.

```
public class ReminderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;   
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
ImageView firstStar,secondStar,thirdStar,fourthStar,fifthStar;   

public ReminderAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    faceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
            "fonts/eau_sans_bold.otf");
    faceNormal = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
            "fonts/eau_sans_book.otf");         

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}    
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;        


   if(activity instanceof SearchDishoom)
   {
       if(convertView==null)
           vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remind_dish_list_row, null);        

       firstStar = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.hotelListFirstStar);
       secondStar = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.hotelListSecondStar);
       thirdStar = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.hotelListThirdStar);
       fourthStar = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.hotelListFourthStar);
       fifthStar = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.hotelListFifthStar);
       firstStar.setFocusable(false);
       secondStar.setFocusable(false);
       thirdStar.setFocusable(false);
       fourthStar.setFocusable(false);
       fifthStar.setFocusable(false);           

       firstStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            setStar(1);

        }
    });
       secondStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //ReminderList.clear();
            setStar(2);                 
        }
    });
       thirdStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            setStar(3);                 
        }
    });
       fourthStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            setStar(4);                 
        }
    });
       fifthStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {                
            setStar(5);                 
        }
    });           
   }       
    return vi;
}


  public void setStar(int btnNumber) {
    if (btnNumber == 1) {       

        firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        //postRating(1);
    }
    if (btnNumber == 2) {           

        firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        //postRating(2);
    }
    if (btnNumber == 3) {           

        firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        //postRating(3);
    }
    if (btnNumber == 4) {

        firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
        //postRating(4);
    }
    if (btnNumber == 5) {

        firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        //postRating(5);
    }
}
```

I don't understand what happening. Please give me any reference or hint.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Onactivity result ,reload listview adapter.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 firstStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            setStar(1);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks little buggy.

As default, adapter reuse their child views, so one important point dealing with adapter is updating value of correct target.

In your code, when a user click a `firstStart`, `setStar` method will be called.

```
firstStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setStar(1);

    }
}
```

In `setStar`, you refer `fireStart` instance, but there is no guarantee that the `fireStar` instance is connected to the expected one. For example, if there are more than one item in ListView, the `fireStart` instance will be overwritten whenever your `getView` method is called.

```
public void setStar(int btnNumber) {
    if (btnNumber == 1) {

        firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        ...
        //postRating(1);
    }
    ...
}
```

So, what you need is maintaing a reference to correct target. One easy way to archive this is using ViewHolder pattern in your adapter. Something like this...

```
class ViewHolder {
    View firstStar;
    View secondStar;
    ...
}

ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.firstStar = firstStar;
holder.secondStar = secondStar;

fireStar.setTag(holder);
firstStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        ViewHolder holder = arg0.getTag();
        //update images inside holder,
        //instead of refer 'adapter instance scope field members'.
        holder.firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
    }
}
```

There is a good article about ViewHolder pattern in android, Check -
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` ----
Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

It means that any view which shows/is based on/uses that data should be invalidated(remeasured, redrawn) in order to show the user the new set of data.

[NotifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

```
firstStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            setStar(1);
            your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```